# PHP how to retrieve array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array, I want to retrieve `name`, `comment` and `each of the tags` (to insert in database. How can i retrieve the array values. Also, can i filter ONLY the tags values which are larger than 3 characters and contains only a-Z0-9 valueus. Thank you very much.

```
Array
(
    [folder] => /test
    [name] => ajay
    [comment] => hello world.. test comment
    [item] => Array
        (
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => javascript
                    [1] => coldfusion
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: See [PHP manual](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) on how to access array values. Filtering may be done via [regex](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php)

Comment: You should view my questions i've asked a load about this topic and how different circumstances it can be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$name = $array['name'];
$comment = $array['comment'];
$tags = $array['item']['tags']; // this will be an array of the tags
```

You can then loop over the tags like:

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
  // do something with tag
}
```

Or access each one individually

```
echo $tags[0];
echo $tags[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$name = $array['name'];
echo $name; // ajay

$comment = $array['comment']
echo $comment;  //hello world.. test comment

$tags = $array['item']['tags'];
echo $tags[0]; // javascript
echo $tags[1]; // coldfusion
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1):

To filter tags longer than 3 chars and only tags contain a-z, A-Z, 0-9 you can use this code

```
$alltags =  $your_array["item"]["tags"];

$valid_tags = array();
foreach($alltags as $tag)
  if ((preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $tag) == 1) && (strlen($tag) > 3)) $valid_tags[] = $tag;
```

Use it like

```
print_r($valid_tags);
```