# How to print an array value in another php file?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an API result in [this page](http://adu.ir/lFmJ6)
How to print for example: annually price of product that it's id = 68 (first one) (in this case annually price is 500000.00 ) in another php file?
this is an internal api of whmcs.
thank you

```
Array
(
  [result] => success
  [totalresults] => 4
  [products] => Array
    (
      [product] => Array
        (
          [0] => Array
            (
              [pid] => 68
              [gid] => 16
              [type] => hostingaccount
              [name] => IR-CL100
              [description] => <li>حجم دیسک<strong>۱۰۰ مگابایت</strong></li>
<li>ترنسفر ماهیانه<strong>۲ گیگابایت</strong></li>
<li>پارک دومین <strong>رایگان</strong></li>
<li>دومین افزوده<strong>۱۰/۰۰۰ تومان</strong></li>
<li>تعداد MySQL<strong>۱ عدد</strong></li>

              [module] => directadmin
              [paytype] => recurring
              [pricing] => Array
                (
                  [IRR] => Array
                    (
                      [prefix] => 
                      [suffix] =>  ریال
                      [msetupfee] => 100000.00
                      [qsetupfee] => 50000.00
                      [ssetupfee] => 0.00
                      [asetupfee] => 0.00
                      [bsetupfee] => 0.00
                      [tsetupfee] => 0.00
                      [monthly] => 50000.00
                      [quarterly] => 150000.00
                      [semiannually] => 300000.00
                      [annually] => 500000.00
                      [biennially] => 900000.00
                      [triennially] => -1.00
                    )

                )

              [customfields] => Array
                (
                  [customfield] => Array
                    (
                    )

                )

              [configoptions] => Array
                (
                  [configoption] => Array
                    (
                      [0] => Array
                        (
                          [id] => 31
                          [name] => سایت افزوده
                          [type] => 4
                          [options] => Array
                            (
                              [option] => Array
                                (
                                  [0] => Array
                                    (
                                      [id] => 59
                                      [name] => سایت افزوده - میزبانی بیش از یک سایت در یک حساب کاربری
                                      [recurring] => 
                                      [pricing] => Array
                                        (
                                          [IRR] => Array
                                            (
                                              [msetupfee] => 50000.00
                                              [qsetupfee] => 0.00
                                              [ssetupfee] => 0.00
                                              [asetupfee] => 0.00
                                              [bsetupfee] => 0.00
                                              [tsetupfee] => 0.00
                                              [monthly] => 10000.00
                                              [quarterly] => 30000.00
                                              [semiannually] => 60000.00
                                              [annually] => 100000.00
                                              [biennially] => 200000.00
                                              [triennially] => 300000.00
                                            )

                                        )

                                    )

                                )

                            )

                        )

                      [1] => Array
                        (
                          [id] => 63
                          [name] => دیسک اضافی
                          [type] => 4
                          [options] => Array
                            (
                              [option] => Array
                                (
                                  [0] => Array
                                    (
                                      [id] => 166
                                      [name] => گیگابایت دیسک اضافی
                                      [recurring] => 
                                      [pricing] => Array
                                        (
                                          [IRR] => Array
                                            (
                                              [msetupfee] => 50000.00
                                              [qsetupfee] => 0.00
                                              [ssetupfee] => 0.00
                                              [asetupfee] => 0.00
                                              [bsetupfee] => 0.00
                                              [tsetupfee] => 0.00
                                              [monthly] => 100000.00
                                              [quarterly] => 300000.00
                                              [semiannually] => 600000.00
                                              [annually] => 1200000.00
                                              [biennially] => 2400000.00
                                              [triennially] => 3600000.00
                                            )

                                        )

                                    )

                                )

                            )

                        )

                      [2] => Array
                        (
                          [id] => 33
                          [name] => پهنای باند اضافه
                          [type] => 4
                          [options] => Array
                            (
                              [option] => Array
                                (
                                  [0] => Array
                                    (
                                      [id] => 61
                                      [name] => ۱۰ گیگابایت ترنسفر ماهیانه برای سایت های پر بازدید
                                      [recurring] => 
                                      [pricing] => Array
                                        (
                                          [IRR] => Array
                                            (
                                              [msetupfee] => 50000.00
                                              [qsetupfee] => 0.00
                                              [ssetupfee] => 0.00
                                              [asetupfee] => 0.00
                                              [bsetupfee] => 0.00
                                              [tsetupfee] => 0.00
                                              [monthly] => 50000.00
                                              [quarterly] => 150000.00
                                              [semiannually] => 300000.00
                                              [annually] => 600000.00
                                              [biennially] => 1200000.00
                                              [triennially] => 1800000.00
                                            )

                                        )

                                    )

                                )

                            )

                        )

                    )

                )

            )

        )

    )

)
```

Comment: You can use $_SESSION variable to store this result and fetch in another page.

Comment: this "API" is returning the results of a `print_r`. Is there a way u can modify that so that it returns JSON instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP how to retrieve array values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568901/php-how-to-retrieve-array-values)

Comment: Thanks. yes. How to modify that to make return json instead? @CodeGodie

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/json'); echo json_encode($array);`

Comment: Godd Job. Thank You very much. Works! @CodeGodie

Comment: Nice. ill place an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your API is returning the contents of `print_r`, it should instead return JSON:

do this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
echo json_encode($array);
```